# About GLib.Idle on Vala

Tags: glib, vala

Valadoc is not very well documented in some parts, the namespace Idle in GLib has no description whats they do, there are only a few functions to define a priory level for idle event!

Someone know whats this does?

```
Functions:

public uint add (owned SourceFunc function, int priority = DEFAULT_IDLE)
public uint add_full (int priority, owned SourceFunc function)
public bool remove_by_data (void* data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt refer to the C documentation:

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-idle-add

> Adds a function to be called whenever there are no higher priority
>   events pending to the default main loop. The function is given the
>   default idle priority, G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE. If the function
>   returns FALSE it is automatically removed from the list of event
>   sources and will not be called again.
>
> See memory management of sources for details on how to handle the
>   return value and memory management of data .
>
> This internally creates a main loop source using g_idle_source_new()
>   and attaches it to the global GMainContext using g_source_attach(), so
>   the callback will be invoked in whichever thread is running that main
>   context. You can do these steps manually if you need greater control
>   or to use a custom main context.

In general you may want to read about the main loop:

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.description

> The main event loop manages all the available sources of events for
>   GLib and GTK+ applications. These events can come from any number of
>   different types of sources such as file descriptors (plain files,
>   pipes or sockets) and timeouts. New types of event sources can also be
>   added using g_source_attach().
>
> To allow multiple independent sets of sources to be handled in
>   different threads, each source is associated with a GMainContext. A
>   GMainContext can only be running in a single thread, but sources can
>   be added to it and removed from it from other threads.
>
> Each event source is assigned a priority. The default priority,
>   G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, is 0. Values less than 0 denote higher priorities.
>   Values greater than 0 denote lower priorities. Events from high
>   priority sources are always processed before events from lower
>   priority sources.
>
> Idle functions can also be added, and assigned a priority. These will
>   be run whenever no events with a higher priority are ready to be
>   processed.
>
> [...]

Comment: Is main_loop and idle the same thing?

Comment: I used idle for the same effect of main_loop and works as well! I also thought it was the best reference I could find, Pantheon is a Gnome fork, so I guess that just might be the answer.

Comment: Idle is just an easy way to add an event to the main loop.